# Aws dynamodb hour range query

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I'm developing a service providing a platform for surfers to report wave state(good to surf or not etc.) on aws(s3 static website and dynamodb) recently. 
The most frequency query may be last-three-hours reports(or last-six-hours, still not a stable decision yet). 
So I wanna use `query` to optimize this but I don't know how I set the Index.

I have considered set a range key for `yyyyMMddhh` field. 
Then I can use `KeyConditionExpression` to set some great-than and less than query.
Because in this query(last-three-hours), there are not any hash key.
reports uuid? no! user Id? no!
I don't need to assign any specified reports uuid or user Id to query actually.

So is any suggestion to optimize this query?
Or, only `scan` is available for this case?

#### Schema may be:

- userId - s
- timestamp - n
- yyyyMMddhh - n
- picture_uuid - s
- location - s
- comment - s
- surf_type - s
- rating - n

Comment: what do you want to query exactly? wave state for given location? or wave state reported by given user?

Comment: wave state for all my country(Taiwan)

Comment: If this project becomes the global-scale app, maybe my requirement is what  you said(wave state for given location)

Comment: But now this project is for a small island country, so the query I ask for is query all the wave state report for specified times( suppose last three hours).